# The form of the verb in attributive clause when the subject in main clause is "I"

Tags: clauses, attributives, third-person-singular

For example, which of the following is correct?

> I am a teacher who likes teaching.

or

> I am a teacher who like teaching.

Comment: Teacher" is 3 sg, so the verb should match it: "likes" is thus correct

Answer (score 0):

The verb here is governed by the pronoun used. In English, *who* can be both singular and plural.

Since there is no way to tell the number of that pronoun from the bare pronoun itself, you have to look at the original noun it points to.

If the subject noun is singular, make it singular.

> I am a teacher who **likes** teaching.

If the subject noun is plural, make it plural.

> We are teachers who **like** teaching.